# Stored procedure occasionally executes twice

Tags: .net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a .net console application that collects some basic inventory information from a computer and/ user.  It dumps this info into a SQL Server 2012 database via a stored procedure.

I am having an occasional occurrence of duplicate records in at least two of tables.

The stored procedure is pretty simple, when the stored procedure receives a serial number (among other parameters) it searches an asset table for the the serial. If a match is found the the `assetId` is returned otherwise a new entry is created and the newly created `assetId` is returned. Also in the procedure, a date time entry is added to an event table using the previously returned `assetId`.

What I'm beginning to see is two records in the asset table with sequential `assetId` numbers, but having the same serial number. What's interesting is that there will be two records in the event table that correspond to each of these `assetId`'s that have the EXACT same `date_time`.

Out of the 22,000+ computers we have, this has only happened on five serial numbers so it's not the end of the world for me. However, for I've been questioned on the reliability of the rest of the data due to this issue.

Any ideas how this might occur?

**Stored Procedure**

```
    --Create an asset row if there is not one and retrieve the id. Or just retrieve the id.
If (select count(assetid) from asset where serial=@serial) > 0
Begin
    set @assetid = (select top 1 assetid from asset where serial=@serial )
End
Else 
    --Add asset to table
    Begin
        Insert into asset (serial, model, manufacturer) 
        values (@serial, @model, @manufacturer);

        set @assetid = (Select SCOPE_IDENTITY())
    End
    --End Asset entry

    --Insert Audit Event record
    Insert into auditevent (assetid, audittime, username, computername, operatingsystem) 
    values (@assetid, @audittime, @username, @computername, @operatingsystem)

    Declare @auditeventid int = (select SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    --Send the ipString to the function that will convert it to a table and insert into IP Table
    Insert into ipaddress (auditeventid, ipaddress) 
        select * 
        from CsvToTable(@auditeventid, @ipaddressvalues)
```

**Console app (single thread)**

```
    Dim strExcutionCommand As String = "dbo.auditclient @computername=N'" & strComputerName & "',@modeltext=N'" & strModel & "',@serial=N'" & strSerialNumber & "',@username=N'" & strUserName & "',@manufacturertext=N'" & strManufacturer & "',@operatingsystemtext=N'" & strOperatingSystem & "',@ipaddressvalues=N'" & strNetAddress & "'"


    Dim Inv_ConnectString As String = "Data Source=cen-support01;Initial Catalog=IT_Inventory;User Id=" & strSqlUser & ";Password=" & strSqlPw & ";"
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(Inv_ConnectString)

    Dim myCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strExcutionCommand, myConnection)
    myConnection.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: Why are you auditing from the application, that is a database antipattern?

Comment: I suggest making `asset.assetid` a primary key to avoid duplicates even if there is a bug somewhere else.  I also suggest wrapping all your statements with `begin transaction` / `commit`.

Comment: BTW, I think the issue is on the console application that calls the stored proc, or on how the console application is triggered for execution.

Comment: @HLGEM  I don't that know of any other way to quickly accomplish the task. I've considered a server-driven model, but requires much more code and debugging which = time.  What would be a better model?

Comment: @wdosanjos  asset.assetid is in fact PK. The duplicate records I suppose are actually different in that the assetid field is incremented by one.

Comment: Then put a Unique Key constraint on `asset.serial`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not easy to diagnose this issue without seeing the code for your console application along with details of how it runs. For example, could you run multiple instances and have 2 threads attempt to do the same task at the same time?

You could test if this is the cause by running the console application twice when there is an inventory item to add and see if it is duplicated.

The logic of the stored procedure seems fine, although I would re-write it somewhat:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM asset WHERE serial=@serial) 
   -- Create an asset row if it doesn't exist
    BEGIN
        SELECT @assetid = assetid FROM asset WHERE serial=@serial
    END
ELSE 
    --Add asset to table    
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO asset (serial,model,manufacturer) 
        VALUES (@serial,@model,@manufacturer);

        SELECT @assetid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    END
```

This is untested, but you should get the idea.

Comment: See my added console code above.  It's a very simple program.  It's single threaded so not running any functions twice.  It gathers data from WMI, stores to variables and saves to db via stored procedure.